# Snap update requires Firefox (and all google sites) to re-sync!

Tags: firefox, snap

Really!!!

I hope it's just me and this isn't what I should expect of SNAP applications.  But this is the second time SNAP Firefox has updated and I am required to re-sync my Firefox account and all Google sync'd websites.

It is as if I have never used this computer before!!!

The list of Google security warnings I am receiving in my email are becoming "Cry Wolf!!!"

How can I avoid this from happening on every SNAP update?

Comment: Hmmm. Has not happend to me, so your experience is not universal. It might be just you.

Comment: You can replace the Firefox snap with the apt version: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/1004020

Comment: a more uptodate version of the methodology to install FF as a deb package is [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04)